# Facultative compilation : errors with \ifdefined

Tags: verbatim

I'm trying to defined a compilation option in a document, in order to possibly compile only part of it. Here my code :

```
\def\compiletotale{} % to be commented or not
\newcommand{\compilefacultative}[1]{
  \ifdefined\compiletotale
    #1
  \fi
}
```

It seems to work with simple usages, as for example

```
\compilefacultative{
  
  Bonjour.
  
}
```

However I have several errors with more complex usages, as for example

```
\compilefacultative{
\begin{verbatim}
Bonjour...
\end{verbatim}
}
```

> Undefined control sequence \end{verbatim}

Thanks for yours ideas to make it work.

Comment: You cannot have `verbatim` in the argument to another command.

Comment: @egreg: thanks, I didn't known. However I would like to use my \compilefacultative{} command over another long part of my document, in which there is no verbatim, but a lot of others things including \part{} to \subsection{} commands, theorems, etc. It does not work either. Are there many things you cannot put as arguments of a command?